# Necesito encontrar palabras repetidas en un array

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando comprobar si existe alguna palabra repetida en mi array, pero no funciona como imaginaba. No consigo que me aparezcan ni las palabras repetidas ni las que están sin repetir.

Explico un poco lo que he intentado hacer:

Primero creo una variable que pida por pantalla una cadena de texto. A continuación, le aplico la función `split()` para que me separe las palabras y me lo convierta en un array. Posteriormente, recorro ese array de palabras con un bucle `for` para convertirlas todas a minúsculas (para que no haya ningún tipo de diferencia entre una palabra y otra. Además, supongo también que no hay signos de puntuación).

Luego, creo dos variables para almacenar las palabras que estén repetidas y las que no, y es aquí donde tengo el problema.

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal, pero intento recorrer la variable texto y con la función `indexOf` descubrir si hay una palabra repetida. No obstante, no obtengo el resultado deseado, que sería tener dos arrays: uno con las palabras repetidas y otro con las palabras que no se repiten.

```js
var entrada = prompt("Introduzca el texto a analizar");

var texto = entrada.split(" ");

console.log(texto);

for (var i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
    texto[i] = texto[i].toLowerCase();
}

console.log(texto);

var sinRepetir = [];
var repetidas = [];

for (var i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
    if (texto.indexOf(texto[i]) != -1) {
        repetidas.push(texto[i]);
    } else {
        sinRepetir.push(texto[i]);
    }
}


console.log(repetidas);
console.log(sinRepetir);
```

Comment: cambia `texto.indexOf(texto[i]) != -1` por `texto.indexOf(texto[i]) != 0`. Eso solucionara el problema, pero te recomiendo que dentro del else metas otra condición para no acabar por ejemplo con la palabra repetida X veces y aparezca solo una o con un contador. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, pero no me funciona correctamente. Se me queda el array vacío. Además, si pongo distinto de 0 podría ser que diese -1, 3, 68, 94... No se si me explico.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías jugar con los métodos del prototipo [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array#M.C3.A9todos), por ejemplo [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) es uno que te puede servir muy bien en esto.

Te propongo el siguiente modelo:

Tienes un array de palabras, que quieres saber si se repite.

- En primer lugar obtenemos un nuevo Array con todas las palabras en lowercase. El método[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) nos ayuda en esto. Devuelve un nuevo array con los elementos del Array tras aplicar una función sobre ellos. En este caso, `toLowerCase()`.
- Sobre el nuevo Array iteramos por cada palabra. El método [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) permite ejecutar una función sobre cada elemento de un Array.
- Para saber si la palabra se repite, podemos usar [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para tener un array que sólo contenga la palabra en cuestión, las veces que haga falta.
- Si del resultado de la operación obtenemos un array de longitud mayor a 1, entonces lo añadimos a `repetidos`, si la longitud es 1, entonces lo añadimos a no-repetidos.
- Reducimos los valores repetidos del array de valores repetidos utilizando un [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set), así no tienes múltiples veces guardado el mismo valor.

Para muestra, un botón, aquí te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
const input = prompt("Introduzca el texto a analizar");

const inputToArray = input.split(' ');
const normalizedInputArray = inputToArray.map(el => el.toLowerCase()); // obtenemos un nuevo Array con todas las palabras en minúscula usando Array.map()
let repeatedWords = [];
let uniqueWords = [];

normalizedInputArray.forEach(value => {
  normalizedInputArray.filter(el => el === value).length > 1
  ? repeatedWords.push(value)
  : uniqueWords.push(value);
});

const uniqueRepeatedWords = [...new Set(repeatedWords)]

console.log(uniqueRepeatedWords);
console.log(uniqueWords)
```

Answer (score 0):

Existen mucha maneras de hacer esto de forma sencilla. Por supuesto todos esto metodos e instrucciones tienen un respaldo nativo. Este ejemplo puede que no sea óptimo con muchos datos pero la expresión de indexado hash ayuda un poco `objeto[llave]`.

```js
var res = (prompt("Introduzca la cadena a procesar:")||"").replace(/\s{2,}/, ' ')
  .split(' ')
  .reduce((inicial, palabra, indice, arrayPalabras, objPalabra, pMinuscula) =>
           //Las expresiones encerradas en parentesis y separadas por comas son instrucciones a ejecutar por separado y en orden secuencial. 
            (pMinuscula = palabra.toLowerCase(), //unifico los valores
             objPalabra = (inicial[pMinuscula] = (inicial[pMinuscula]||{})), //Si no existe lo registro y si no obtengo una referencia y lo guardo en la variable "objPalabra"
             (objPalabra.palabras = objPalabra.palabras || []).push(palabra), //Si no existe el arreglo lo creo y si no obtengo una referencia y añado la palabra original al arreglo
             inicial), 
          {});

console.log(res);

console.log("Obtener las palabras repetidas", Object.keys(res).filter(p => res[p].palabras.length > 1));



console.log("Oración con la primera palabra de cada conjunto se repita o no: ", Object.keys(res).map(p => res[p].palabras[0]).join(' '));
```

Espero sirva de ayuda...

Answer (score -1):

cómo estás?

Esta podría ser una solución:

```js
var string = "Algo para analizar algo"; //este sería tu string ingresado

var repetidos = [];
var noRepetidos = [];

for(var i = 0; i < string.toLowerCase().split(" ").length; i++){

 var element = string.toLowerCase().split(" ")[i];

 var cant = string.toLowerCase().split(" ").reduce(function(n, val)   {
  return n + (val === element);
 }, 0);

  if(cant > 1){
    //esta repetido
    //si el elemento ya existe no lo guardo
    if(repetidos.indexOf(element) === -1){
      repetidos.push(element);
    }
  }else{
    noRepetidos.push(element);
  }
}

console.log(repetidos);
console.log(noRepetidos);
```

Perdona si no quedó bien indentado, me cuesta con las herramientas que aquí tengo para escribir jaja.

El problema que estabas teniendo con tu código es que al tu preguntar si cada elemento del for se encontraba en tu array "indexOf" siempre te daba como resultado que SÍ, estaba, porque claro, estás comparando el propio elemento en el que estás actualmente con el total del array y siempre te va a dar que al menos 1 hay.

indexOf te devuelve inmediatamente la posición del primer elemento encontrado, no te devuelve más de una posición.

Cualquier duda que tengas, puedes preguntar.

Saludos y éxitos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero mi nivel de JS es muy básico y hay muchas cosas que no sé ni lo que son jajajaja. ¿Sería posible hacerlo con las mismas funciones que he utilizado?