# Ver palabras repetidas en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo un array que contiene texto.

```
const array = ['primer texto aleatorio','segundo texto','tercer texto']
```

Lo que quiero hacer y no encuentro la forma es, saber si una palabra se repite o es unica. Por ejemplo "texto" se repite tres veces osea que no es una palabra unica. Y "aleatorio" si es una palabra unica.

Comment: Creo que hay preguntas similares sobre conteo de repetidos

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271453/necesito-encontrar-palabras-repetidas-en-un-array`

Comment: Para resolverlo eficientemente puedes utilizar un algoritmo de pattern matching. El de [Rabin Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) te podría servir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible forma es usando `reduce` junto con [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), se podría usar un objeto, pero para este caso la sintáxis es mucho mas cómoda. El criterio sobre que consideramos "palabra" podría cambiar, tambien podemos elegir usar una regex `\w+` o `[a-z]+` por ejemplo.

```js
const arr = ['primer texto aleatorio', 'segundo texto', 'tercer texto', "algo algo texto texto"]


const res = arr.reduce((p, c) => {

  c.split(" ").forEach(e => {

    p.set(e, p.has(e) ? p.get(e) + 1 : 1)

  })

  return p;

}, new Map())


console.log([...res]) // <-- Todas, con las ocurrencias

const unicas = []

const repetidas = []

res.forEach((v, k) => v === 1 ? unicas.push(k) : repetidas.push(k));

console.log(unicas)

console.log(repetidas)
```

Para saber las ocurrencias de una palabra en particular Ej: "algo" hacemos `res.get("algo")`.

Answer (score 1):

una buena forma para que lo implementes en varios lugares es crear una funcion, aqui te dejo la forma que se me ocurrio :)

```
const array = ['primer texto aleatorio','segundo texto','tercer texto']
var palabra = "primer";`introducir el código aquí`
function array_word(palabra, array) {
var count=0;
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    { 
        if(array[i].includes(palabra))
            {
                count++;
            }
    }
return count;
}
document.write(array_word(palabra,array))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Algo mas corto podría ser**:

```js
const array = ['primer texto primer aleatorio','segundo texto','tercer texto']

const newArr = array
               .map(e => e.split(' '))
               .flat()
               .filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i)

console.log(newArr.filter((e,i,a) => a.indexOf(e) === i)) // Es lo mismo que abajo
console.log([...new Set(newArr)]) // Es lo mismo que arriba pero resumido
```

**Explicación completa del código**:

En este ejemplo mapeamos el array para separar cada palabra individualmente y con flat lo ponemos todo al mismo nivel, de esta manera tenemos un array de solo palabras y luego aplicamos un par de filtros con dos condiciones muy similares, en el primero si el index de la primera palabra encontrada no coincide con el index del item actual, esto quiere decir que esta repetido por lo tanto se filtra el item, en el segundo lo contrario, como solo queremos saber cuales palabras están repetidas y no todas las veces que se repite limpiamos el array con un nuevo filtro, indicando que si el index del item actual corresponde a al index de la primera coincidencia (con indexOf) se filtra de lo contrario no y significa que está repetido.

**Si quisiésemos saber cuantas repeticiones hay pues en lugar de filtrar, mapeamos el array final**:

```js
const array = ['primer texto primer aleatorio','segundo texto','tercer texto']

const newArr = array
               .map(e => e.split(' '))
               .flat()
               .filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i)
               .map((e, i, a) => ({[e]: a.filter(str => str === e).length + 1}));

console.log(Object.assign({}, ...newArr))
```

Acá mapeamos un array de objetos filtrando y contando las repeticiones y luego con Object.assign unimos el array en un objeto con la cuenta de las incidencias.

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.